# Removing instance from DbContext throws duplicate Id error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, invalidoperationexception

I have a test that seeds the database, then calls a method that loads a seeded object and deletes it. However, when the method goes to call `dbContext.Remove(...)`, I get an error that says,

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'FiveWhysAnalysis' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

My code looks like so...

Seed.cs

```cs
public Seed(MyContext dbContext) {
    this.dbContext = dbContext;
}

public Task Seed() {
    this.DataStory = new DataStory(...)
    this.FiveWhyAnalysis = new FiveWhyAnalysis(this.DataStory.Id, ...) // Doesn't touch Id property
    this.dbContext.FiveWhyAnalyses.Add(fivewhy);
    return this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

DeleteFiveWhyMutator.cs

```cs
public DeleteFiveWhyMutator(MyContext dbContext, int dataStoryId) {
    this.dbContext = dbContext;
    this.dataStoryId = dataStoryId;
}

public async Task Load(MyContext dbContext) {
    DataStory dataStory = await dbContext.DataStories.FirstAsync(ds => ds.Id == this.dataStoryId);
    dataStory.FiveWhysAnalysis = await dbContext.FiveWhysAnalyses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(fw => fw.DataStoryId == dataStory.Id);

    // NOTE: I have also tried using an include by doing:
    // DataStory dataStory = await dbContext.DataStories.Include(ds => ds.FiveWhyAnalysis).FirstAsync(ds => ds.Id == this.dataStoryId);
    // rather than the above implementation of this method.
    return dataStory;
}

public async Task<DataStory> Run(MyContext dbContext, DataStory dataStory) {
    dbContext.FiveWhysAnalyses.Remove(dataStory.FiveWhysAnalysis); // Error here
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return dataStory;
}
```

DeleteFiveWhyMutatorTest.cs

```cs
MyContext dbContext = ... // Injected using Microsoft DI
Seed seed = new Seed(dbContext);
await seed.Seed();
var mutator = new DeleteFiveWhyMutator(dbContext, seed.DataStory.Id);
DataStory dataStory = await mutator.Load(dbContext);
await mutator.Run(dbContext);
```

Comment: You can try 2 changes. Include `async` as `public async Task Seed()` and add `await` in return call as  `return await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

Quite a bit about this example scenario feels wrong. For instance this:

```
DataStory dataStory = await dbContext.DataStories.FirstAsync(ds => ds.Id == this.dataStoryId);
dataStory.FiveWhysAnalysis = await dbContext.FiveWhysAnalyses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(fw => fw.DataStoryId == dataStory.Id);
```

If DataStory already has a navigation property for FiveWhysAnalysis and you want to fetch the associated one:

```
DataStory dataStory = await dbContext.DataStories.Include(ds => ds.FiveWhysAnalysis).FirstAsync(ds => ds.Id == this.dataStoryId);
```

Eager load it, as you mention you have tried. This is the correct way. Loading related entities as extra queries and overwriting the navigation property is unnecessary and potentially error prone.

Next would be potential overuse of async operations. While these are great for offloading long running queries to free up a web server to start other requests while waiting for a response, they should generally not be defaulted to. Calling multiple DbContext calls /w async can result in those calls crossing threads, and the DbContext is not thread-safe. For example, if you update your example to:

```
public async Task Load(MyContext dbContext) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread @1: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    DataStory dataStory = await dbContext.DataStories.FirstAsync(ds => ds.Id == this.dataStoryId);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread: @2" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    dataStory.FiveWhysAnalysis = await dbContext.FiveWhysAnalyses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(fw => fw.DataStoryId == dataStory.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("Thread: @3" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

   //...
}
```

You will see an output something like:
Thread @1: 13
Thread @2: 14
Thread @3: 15

Depending on how the application is configured to run, async operations resume execution on a different thread than they were called. This is generally "ok" so long as *all* operations are awaited. AFAIK the DbContext will not throw a fit from requests resuming on an alternative thread so long as it's one thread at a time. However, if you forget or neglect to await an operation then you can get stung with cross-thread access. Async operations also add overhead so they're really suited to being used sparingly for just the queries you expect to take more than a moment to execute. Using them by default will make your code marginally slower overall.

Next you mention using Dependency Injection, though your methods are all constructed to accept a DbContext, which defeats the purpose of the dependency injection. I would also look at how your DbContext is lifetime scoped to ensure that it is not Transient, but scoped per request or an explicit scope. A DbContext should only be needed on the constructors of your clases and the DI should ensure all classes constructed receive the same DbContext instance. (Not passing DbContexts around in methods)

Your return types also don't make sense. You have return Task but don't use it, and have public methods to "load" an entity when the purpose of a mutator is to control how object instances are manipulated. Nothing about this pattern implementation prevents someone from just loading the entity and having their way with it. It has a code smell of complexity with no clear purpose.

None of these points alone I think explain the behaviour you are seeing, but in combination they could be hiding a bad assumption leading to multiple references being linked to the DbContext which is already tracking an matching instance. I would recommend starting by implementing the simplest thing first, verifying the behavior then gradually re-factoring for the desired patterns you are trying to accomplish. Firstly, remove all async operations and fix up the DI so that the DbContext references are only initialized on the constructors. Fetch the entity /w eager loading, then call your mutator.

```
public DeleteFiveWhyMutator(MyContext dbContext, int dataStoryId) {
    this.dbContext = dbContext;
    this.dataStoryId = dataStoryId;
}

private FiveWhyAnalysis GetAnalysis() {
    var fwAnalysis = dbContext.DataStories
       .Where(ds => ds.Id = dataStoryId)
       .Select(ds => ds.FiveWhyAnalysis)
       .SingleOrDefault();
    return fwAnalysis;
}

public void Run() {
    var fwAnalysis = GetAnalysis();
    if (fwAnalysis == null)
        return;

    dbContext.FiveWhysAnalyses.Remove(fwAnalysis);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Then in the test:

```
using (var dbContext = new MyContext()) // Real code will DI the context.
{
    Seed seed = new Seed(dbContext); 
    seed.Seed(); // remove async here as well to test.

    // Assert we have a FiveWhy...
    Assert.IsNotNull(seed.DataStory.FiveWhyAnalysis, "FiveWhyAnalysis was not seeded.");
    var mutator = new DeleteFiveWhyMutator(dbContext, seed.DataStory.Id);
    mutator.Run();

    // Assert the FiveWhy was removed...
    Assert.IsNull(seed.DataStory.FiveWhyAnalysis, "FiveWhyAnalysis was not removed.");
}
```

If this works, expand out from there. Overall I would advise caution with a pattern implementation like this as it will potentially involve several mutators or other classes sharing a DbContext reference all calling `SaveChanges()` at various times which can result in partial changes being committed by different stages of a larger operation.  Extending the mutator can include a Run method for existing DataStory references:

```
public void Run(DataStory dataStory) {
    if (dataStory == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dataStory");

    if (dataStory.FiveWhyAnalysis == null)
        return;

    dbContext.FiveWhysAnalyses.Remove(dataStory.FiveWhyAnalysis);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This alternative could be called in cases where you've already loaded a data story and wanted to use the mutator to manage removing the FiveWhyAnalysis. For this pattern to have much value over modifying the entity state directly, it would need to provide additional value such as wrapping auditing, change tracking, or other common behaviour.

Comment: Hmm... you have given me a lot to think about. I will try these and see if it works